# Dynamically adding usercontrols to an update panel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, user-controls

Can someone point me in the right direction of adding usercontrols to an update panel.

Basically I have a usercontrol that is setup to capture a persons education details. I want to have a button inside the update that when the user clicks loads the usercontrol below the previous usercontrol.

Any help would be great.

I have got as far as

```
  UserControl userControl = (UserControl)this.LoadControl(controlName);
  this.Panel1.Controls.Add(userControl);
```

however I am not sure how to keep the orginal usercontrol and not overwrite it with the newly loaded usercontrol.